# How can I specify JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH when running storm topology as a local cluster?

Tags: apache-storm

I want to run a storm topology on a local cluster for testing. My code requires some C++ and python libraries. Where do I specify the JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH for it? I am running it from eclipse.

I am including storm as a maven dependency.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
        <artifactId>storm-core</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.2-incubating</version>
</dependency>
```

I found out that its being picked up from defaults.yaml inside storm-core jar. So I extract the jar, changed the file and created the jar again and the new path is picked up. Any other way to specify it in the code or a separate config file which can be picked up at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is another way from eclipse but you can download storm, jar up your code and run it from storm bin.  This way you can set your JAVA_LIB in the storm.yaml along with any other settings you want to change. Storm.yaml is in the conf dir and it will be picked up.  Make sure in your main u set it to deploy to the local cluster.